# Внесение изменений в объект

Tags: javascript

Имеется объект:

```
sptn={"orders":[{"externalOrderId":19,"externalCustomerId":0,"status":"INITIALIZED","date":"2017-08-10 19:25:17","paymentMethod":"Credit Card","restoreUrl":"market.com","deliveryAddress":", , ","items":[{"externalItemId":"52","name":"\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0434\u043a\u04302","category":"Cameras","quantity":1,"cost":444,"url":"\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=52","imageUrl":"","description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;"}]}]}
```

Необходимо добавить в него еще ключи; добавляю так:

```
sptn.orders =[{"ddd":44,"costin":444}] //стирается все элементы
```

Как можно добавить его, чтобы получить такую структуру?

```
sptn={"orders":[{"externalOrderId":19,"externalCustomerId":0,"ddd":44,"costin":444,"status":"INITIALIZED","date":"2017-08-10 19:25:17","paymentMethod":"Credit Card","restoreUrl":"market.com","deliveryAddress":", , ","items":[{"externalItemId":"52","name":"\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0434\u043a\u04302","category":"Cameras","quantity":1,"cost":444,"url":"\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=52","imageUrl":"","description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), Luke!

```js
let obj = [1, 2];
console.info(obj); // 1, 2
obj.push(3);
console.info(obj); // 1, 2, 3
```

---

Если нужно изменить конкретный ключ массива и добавить в него свойства, то так:

```js
let sptn = {
    "orders": [{
        "externalOrderId": 19,
        "externalCustomerId": 0,
        "ddd": 44,
        "costin": 444,
        "status": "INITIALIZED",
        "date": "2017-08-10 19:25:17",
        "paymentMethod": "Credit Card",
        "restoreUrl": "market.com",
        "deliveryAddress": ", , ",
        "items": [{
            "externalItemId": "52",
            "name": "\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0434\u043a\u04302",
            "category": "Cameras",
            "quantity": 1,
            "cost": 444,
            "url": "\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=52",
            "imageUrl": "",
            "description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;"
        }]
    }]
};

sptn.orders[0].ddd = 44;
sptn.orders[0].costin = 444;

console.info(sptn);
```

Comment: sptn.orders.push('clock':44)
VM1474:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: sptn.orders.push({"clock":44}) // получается два объекта

Comment: @Anton, обновил.

Comment: О ништя к спасибо это работает, хмм когда учился, походу не до учился (незнал что есть let помимо var)